# haskell - how to get specific map from another map

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, hashmap

I want to write a function in Haskell which return specific map from map

I have:

```
import Data.Map as M  
...  
type m1 = M.Map Int Int  
type m2 = M.Map Int m1
```

And I'm trying something like this:

```
getMap :: m1 -> Int -> m1  
getMap e k = do  
ret = M.lookup (M.size e) e  
return $ fromJust $ ret
```

Unfortunately I haven't get `m1` type returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems here:

- you use `do` notation, which usually implies that you are specifying a *monad*.
- even if you want to use a monad, the `ret = ...` syntax is not the supposed way to do that, then it should have been **`ret <- ...`**, with `...` a monad; and
- the name of a type should start with an **uppercase**, not a lowercase;
- the type should probably be `getMap :: M2 -> Int -> M1`.

So a way to solve it is:

```
import Data.Map as M 

type M1 = M.Map Int Int                         -- uppercase types
type M2 = M.Map Int M1                          -- uppercase types

getMap :: M2 -> Int -> M1                       -- different type signature
getMap e k = fromJust $ M.lookup (M.size e) e   -- pure function
```

That being said, semantically, this does *not* make much sense: you fetch the `M.size` of the map and do not even use `k` (regardless what key you give, it will always return the same value int map, or error). I would think that you are looking for:

```
getMap :: M2 -> Int -> M1  
getMap e k = fromJust $ M.lookup k e
```

Or an alternative version:

```
getMap :: M2 -> Int -> M1 
getMap = (fromJust .) . flip M.lookup
```